# Azure DevOps Pipeline Failure : Validate and Generate ARM template error message

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I am very new to DevOps and having an issue with the Validate and Generate ARM template step of the build and verify in DevOps pipeline runs. This was recently working fine, then began to fail after a comment change to a pipeline.

The error starts here and I am not sure what action to take to remedy this.

**WARNING === BaseFileResourceProviderService: _processResource - Failed to load resource, loadingError: NameMismatch, Error: NameMismatch.
ModelService: fetchAllInBackground - start
ModelService: synchronize - finished
ModelService: _backgroundFetch - finished, duration: 34.80889999959618, total nameds: 1
ModelService: _backgroundFetch - finished, total unknown model types
CmdApiApp: Publishable resource count: 0
CmdApiApp: Publishable parameters count: 0
ERROR === CmdApiApp: Failed to export ARM template. Error: {"stack":"Error: No resource found in specified input path: C:\a\1\s/data-factory/. Please set correct path and try again.\n    at Function. (C:\a\1\s\downloads\main.js:2:15895704)\n    at Generator.next ()\n    at s (C:\a\1\s\downloads\main.js:2:13648929)","message":"No resource found in specified input path: C:\a\1\s/data-factory/. Please set correct path and try again."}

=====ERROR=====
Error: Command failed: node  C:\a\1\s\downloads\main.js export C:\a\1\s/data-factory/ /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/***
**

I've tried updating the install node.js, removing the new tables that were pushed to the UAT branch.

Comment: Hey Branden might need some more information to help with this. Perhaps could you start by providing some of the pipeline, specifically the code block that has the changes you mentioned and what the changes are.

Comment: In addition to what Isaac mentioned, please share this information to help us understand your pipeline and your problem. 1. Your pipeline settings. (YAML file or screenshot of the task which failed). 2. Add a variable `system.debug` and set the value to `true`, trigger the pipeline again and share the complete error message in the debug log.